# Generating hex value depending on size of size_t

Tags: c++, c, hex, size-t

I'm trying to generate a value denoting an invalid address. On 32-bit platforms, I want the value 0xaaaaaaaa. On 64-bit platforms, I want 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa. Is there a way to do this without using preprocessor directives?

Comment: C or C++, pick one, they have different solutions.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Preprocessor directives are well defined in both C and C++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor

Comment: Why do you think either of these would be an invalid address? Both are `SIZE_MAX/3*2`, and it is not uncommon for program loaders to partition the address space into three thirds, which would result in addresses around 0xAAAAAAAA or 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA being used.

Comment: `size_t invalid_addr = *(size_t *)(unsigned char[]){0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xaa};`

Comment: What is your original problem? Why do you need an "invalid address"? Why do you think that would solve your original problem? Why don't you want to use the preprocessor for it?

Comment: NULL is an in valid address — and about the only one that the standard (whether that's C or C++) guarantees is invalid.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm writing code that interacts with Zig, where 0xAA... is used to indicate that a variable is undefined. Passing 0 would trip Zig's runtime safety check, since that language does not allow pointer at that address (unless specifically enabled). The code in question deals with situations where a structure has a length of zero and hence has no actual memory assigned to it.

Comment: @cleong Why type `size_t`? If you want a _pointer_ (an invalid address) with the value of `0xAAA...`, using `uintptr_t` would make more sense and then cast it to `void *`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Just forgot that `uintptr_t` exists. In Zig, `usize` is defined as the pointer size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the two's complement representation of integers you can use `memset` declared in header `<string.h>` in C or `std::memset` declared in header `<cstring>` in C++ as for example

```
size_t value;
memset( &value, 0xaa, sizeof( size_t ) );
```

Or in the both languages you can write

```
size_t value = ( size_t )-1 / 3 * 2;
```

Comment: `( size_t )-1 / 3 * 2` works well as long as the # of value bits is even.  I have yet to encounter an odd size one, even if allowed by C.  Of course OP asked only about 32/64.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think that now in most systems there is used the two's complement data representation.

Comment: Vlad from Moscow, Yes 2's is ubiquitous.  Yet 2's complement has little to do with an _unsigned_ type like `size_t`.  Simply commenting about a theoretical machine that might use a `size_t` with an odd number of value bits.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: an architecture with this feature would be quite odd indeed.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, quite odd.  Yet the `max/3*2` trick might be applied to other types too.  Signed types would commonly have trouble.  I've only come across, once, a machine with an _unsigned_ type with odd value bits, a `unsigned long` with 63 bits (and 1 padding).  (pre C99).

Answer (score 3):

In C:  `SIZE_MAX/3*2`.

In C++:  `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()/3*2`.

Comment: I am not sure if `SIZE_MAX` is the largest number `size_t` can hold. IMO it is the maximum size of the object.

Comment: C 2018 7.20.3 specifies preprocessor macros for limits of “other integer types,” including `SIZE_MAX`, which it says is the “limit of `size_t`” and says “The following object-like macros specify the minimum and maximum limits of integer types corresponding to types defined in other standard headers.”

Answer (score 2):

As other comments above have said, `NULL` or `nullptr` is the only true invalid address.

But if you really need a to compute a 32-bit or 64-bit repeating `AA` pairs...

Take advantage that all modern machine architectures will do fine with this and truncate to the lower 32-bit.

```
size_t s = (size_t)(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAULL);
```

You might not even need the `ULL` suffix in the constant.  Different compilers give different warnings about 64-bit literals.

This is more portable:

```
size_t s = (size_t)((0xAAAAAAAAULL << 32) | 0xAAAAAAAA);
```

Comment: Confident that "Different compilers give different warnings" do not complain about a missing LL, but maybe a missing U.  Spec wise `size_t s = (size_t)(0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)` looks sufficient.  Have an example compiler that warns with no suffix?

Answer (score 2):

If you like weird solutions then.

```
size_t getAAAAs(void)
{
    size_t result;
    memset(&result, 0xaa, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}



int main(void)
{
    size_t res = getAAAAs();
    printf("%zx\n", res);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4rjxh1Ge1

It will be optimized out to a simple immediate load. It will cover all possible future sizes of size_t

Comment: `std::memset()` would result in a shorter code and cover even 256- and 512-bit `size_t`.

Comment: @273K indeed :)

Comment: Nitpicking: this only works for architectures with 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 1):

To form an address of `AAA...`, use `uintptr_t`, not `size_t` using a variation of others` answers.

The size of an address is often like `size_t`, yet may differ and its the *optional* `uintptr_t` that usual meets the address-as-an-integer need.

```
// C solution
#include <stdint.h>
void *aaa = (void *) (UINTPTR_MAX/3*2);
```

Alternatively, go right to it.

```
void *aaa;
memcpy(&aaa, 0xAA, sizeof aaa);
```

---

Beware that assigning an arbitrary value to an pointer can lead to UB .

The bit pattern of an address and its converted to/from integer may differ, even if the same size.